# compare two similar data frames and only display differences in R

Tags: r

I have two similar data frames with the same number of columns, but different numbers of rows. Most of the entries between the two are the same, but in a few places there are differences, and these are what I care about. The first column in both data frames serves as a key.

Ideally, I'd like to be able to see whether they've changed, as well as the values from each of the two data frames. My first solution was to create a merged dataframe and re-organize the columns side-by-side like so:

```
df1<-data.frame(gene=c('cyp1a1','cyp2a6','srd5a','slc5a5','cox15'), updated=c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE),version=c(2,3,1,2,1))
df2<-data.frame(gene=c('cyp1a1','cyp2a6','srd5a','slc5a5'), updated=c(FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE),version=c(1,2,1,1))

#merge data frames
comp<-merge(df1,df2, by="gene", all=TRUE)

#re-order columns side-by-side
#probably a better way to do this
ordList<-c(1,2,4,3,5)
comp<-comp[ordList]
```

So now I have a side-by-side comparison data frame. I am unsure about how to iterate over the data frames to perform the comparison. Eventually I would like to create a new data-frame which uses information from the comparison to exclude data that is identical (replace with empty string) and includes data that differs from the first df to the second.

This is what comp looks like now:

```
    gene    updated.x   updated.y   version.x   version.y
1   cox15   FALSE   NA  1   NA
2   cyp1a1  TRUE    FALSE   2   1
3   cyp2a6  TRUE    TRUE    3   2
4   slc5a5  TRUE    FALSE   2   1
5   srd5a   FALSE   FALSE   1   1
```

This is what I want it to look like:

```
gene    updated.x   updated.y   version.x   version.y
1   cox15   FALSE   NA  1   NA
2   cyp1a1  TRUE    FALSE   2   1
3   cyp2a6                  3   2
4   slc5a5  TRUE    FALSE   2   1
5   srd5a
```

In my actual data, I have 14 columns in each data frame, and hundreds of rows. I may be doing similar comparisons in the future, so having a functional way of executing this task would be ideal.

Comment: see "anti-join" and "duplicated"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my suggestion, considering you have 14 columns:

```
library(data.table)
library(magrittr)

z = rbindlist(list(df1,df2), idcol=TRUE)

z[, lapply(.SD, . %>% unique %>% paste(collapse=";")), keyby=gene]
#      gene .id    updated version
# 1:  cox15   1      FALSE       1
# 2: cyp1a1 1;2 TRUE;FALSE     2;1
# 3: cyp2a6 1;2       TRUE     3;2
# 4: slc5a5 1;2 TRUE;FALSE     2;1
# 5:  srd5a 1;2      FALSE       1
```

This shows you which data frame each gene appears in (`.id`) as well as the attributes (`updated` and `version`). This display extends naturally to additional tables, like `list(df1,df2,df3)`.

---

If you really are not interested in unchanged values, you can hide them with an `if` test:

```
z[, lapply(.SD, function(x) 
  if (uniqueN(x)>1) x %>% unique %>% paste(collapse=";")
  else ""
), keyby=gene]
#      gene .id    updated version
# 1:  cox15                       
# 2: cyp1a1 1;2 TRUE;FALSE     2;1
# 3: cyp2a6 1;2                3;2
# 4: slc5a5 1;2 TRUE;FALSE     2;1
# 5:  srd5a 1;2
```

This also hides `.id` for genes only showing up once, but that can be tweaked.

---

**Explanation**. `z` contains all the data, "stacked" or stored in "long" format.

To make the summary table, we use `z[, j, keyby=gene]` where `j` works on the Subset of Data, `.SD`, associated with each `keyby=gene` group and returns a `list` of column vectors for the result.

The `. %>% unique %>% paste(collapse=";")` uses a feature of magrittr. It is just an easy-to-read version of `function(y) paste(unique(y), collapse=";")`. When it starts with `x`, it applies the function to `x`. You can replace it if you prefer to write these in the standard way.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Do you mind expanding a little bit about the sub-setting line, what's going on there? It complicates things a little bit in that a few of my column entries are strings with commas in them already, so alternative ways of displaying this information would be helpful.

Comment: @Tsaari Ok, I've edited so you can use a custom separator instead of `toString`s' `", "`. I'll add some explanation now, though I'm not sure which line looks like subsetting to you. The basic structure is: stack over DFs, split by genes, summarize.

Comment: Alternate form of the second variant: `z[, lapply(.SD, . %>% unique %>% {if (length(.)==1) "" else paste(.,collapse=";")}), keyby=gene]`

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. This is very helpful.